# no executable produced in eclipse after build

Tags: c, eclipse

I have a pre-existing c project where I can `cd` into the directory, type `make` and it will produce an executable.

In eclipse I go to `File->New->Makefile Project with Existing Code` and select the same aforementioned directory. I then go to `Project->Build All`. No errors, but then I check my folder and there is no executable. What's going on? How do I fix this?

If the compiler is correct, and there are no errors in my code, I don't suppose it matters that much. After I'm done coding I can always go back to the terminal to get my executable.

edit: I think the problem is with my makefile. Here it is below:

```
    #
    #       Some comments
    #
    #

    # Compiler
    CC=gcc

    # Common Directory

    # Compiler Flags 
    #CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
    CFLAGS = -g -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
    LFLAGS = 

    LIBS = -L. -llssdk

    INCLUDE = -I .

    OBJS = customer_sample.o

    bot: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o bot $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

    customer_sample.o: customer_sample.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c customer_sample.c

    clean:
        - rm -f *.o bot
```

It says no rule to make target 'all'. I've seen about ten other threads asking the same question, and I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that a Makefile is automatically generated by Eclipse including your source code. The result could be a Makefile that compiles the executable in a different directory which could be under your project directory. Have you checked sub-directories to search for the executable?

Comment: In the project explorer there is only one makefile. So I don't think Eclipse is producing an extra one. Also, yes, I searched around for my executable.